# Selenium Failing to Upload Picture

Tags: image, selenium-webdriver, selenium-edgedriver

I'm facing an issue when uploading a picture through selenium. The HTML code:

```
<form enctype='multipart/form-data' method='post' action='./upload_ss.cgi'>
                        <h1>Upload a new photo here</h1>
                        <br>
                        Allowed files:<br>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Format: PNG</li>
                            <li>Maximum resolution: 1366 x 768 </li>
                        </ul>
                        <input type='hidden' name='csrf_token' value='qxASP72Kg4RFVpSHyCt0_zFA8CYkSB9Rc89bVx8mFHc.'>
                        <input type='file' name='file' accept='image/*' style='width:100%'>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <input type='submit' name='file' value='Upload File' style='width:100%'>
                    </form>
                </section>
            </div>
```

my code:

```
        self.form_screen = self.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//form[@action="./upload_ss.cgi"]')))

        #Inserting the picture
        self.change_picture = self.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[name="file"][accept="image/*"]')))
        self.change_picture.send_keys(picture1_path)
        time.sleep(4)
        self.button_picture = self.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="content"]/section[2]/form/input[3]')))
        self.button_picture.click()
        self.wait.until(EC.staleness_of(self.form_screen))
```

The code works until the send keys part, but when the button is pressed, it goes to "page can't be reached".
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGOUd.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNJcf.png)

I have researched extensively but i coun't find any related issue. Any thoughts?

Thanks all!

Tried several ways to upload it, but none worked. The code works normally for all the other functions, just encountering issues for the upload.

Comment: Does it work if you do it manually? it doesn't look like a selenium issue to me. selenium issue would be unable to fill the upload field or similar. You are doing that already

Comment: Yes, it does work if i do it manually, but selenium gets a (failed) net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED.

Comment: Did you look at other threads on similar topics and reduce the wait time? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48088350/selenium-exception-connection-getting-closed

Comment: Issue resolved:

Since i using the "get" URL using the login/password in it, when uploading the picture, the HTML was coding to a different page then returning. Since the URL from selenium was the username:password@ip/address, the request was getting no response.

the code is now like this:

driver.get("https://username:passoword@www.example.com")
driver.get("www.example.com")

it works perfectly!